# Bypassing elevation when launching a new process

Tags: windows, windows-7, uac

OK, here's my problem: I'm trying to launch a third-party application.  This application is apparently configured to require elevation, presumably via an embedded manifest.  My program is running in the context of a non-administrative user, and I want the third-party application to run in the same context.

When I call CreateProcess it returns error code 740, "The requested operation requires elevation."

I've tried the CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL flag which sounded relevant but it made no difference.

The third party application does work without administrator privilege, e.g., if I disable UAC and then run it as a non-administrator.

Thanks in advance for any tips/ideas you may have.

Comment: The vendor has explained the reason for elevation - the application needs to interact with the user's other processes, which it can't do if they are elevated and it isn't.  In this case of course that isn't an issue because none of the user's processes will be elevated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the environment variable **__compat_layer** for your process to **RunAsInvoker**. If this environment variable is set, CreateProcess will succeed.

You can use the [SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This elevation is also required on some very simple programs that have UPDATE or SETUP or INSTALL in their names; nothing to do with a manifest.  We write code in PICK BASIC that runs on Win2008 and if we write a HELLO WORLD program called UPDATE.TEST we can't run it without elevation.  All we need to do is rename the program to fix...  But annoying, and btws.

Comment: This has to do with manifests! If the EXE does not contain a manifest, then Windows tries to guess whether the program requires elevation. This logic is applied to 32 bit executable images only, and words like _setup_, _install_, and _update_ trigger UAC. If you add the manifest to such .exe requesting `asInvoker` execution level, Windows will respect the setting, and no UAC confirmation is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no way to workaround it.

If UAC is enabled and program manifests that it requires elevation, then the system tries to run this process as elevated. `CreateProcess` would not start such a process if you're not elevated.

Use `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` functions to start this third-party application. These functions will display UAC confirmation and start the process if user clicks *Yes*. Your UI element which starts this third-party application should have UAC-shield to notify users that UAC confirmation will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems odd to me that there isn't any simple way to ignore the manifest.  I believe from what I've read that the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit may offer a solution.

Comment: Also, ShellExecute won't work in this case, because the end user won't actually have the administrative credentials necessary to use the UAC prompt.

Comment: @Harry I haven't seen any articles which mention the manifest could be ignored. That's the point of it: if program declares that it requires administrator permissions, then OS trusts program authors and tries to give them. By the way, what is the declared level: `requireAdministrator` or `highestAvailable`?

Comment: @Harry Users don't have to be part of the administrators group to work with UAC. If they are, then UAC displays a simple confirmation to elevate; if they aren't, they have to provide administrator credentials. In the latter case, however, users wouldn't know administrator password.

Comment: Based on the behaviour, I believe the declared level is requireAdministrator.  I've suggested to the vendor that they change this to highestAvailable which I think would solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case the problem is that it needs to work for an end user who isn't allowed to know any of the admin passwords.

Comment: Turns out there is an answer!  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086978/can-i-stop-an-executable-from-requesting-uac-elevation

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use use the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082(v=vs.85).aspx) to create and install a custom compatibility database that applies the [RunAsInvoker fix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638389(v=ws.10).aspx) or the [RunAsHighest fix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638322(v=ws.10).aspx) to the application in question.  Although the documentation does not say whether or not this works for applications that have requireAdministrator set in the manifest, I have tested this and it works for me.

You can install a compatibility database programmatically using the [sdbinst command-line tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749169(v=ws.10).aspx).

(In most scenarios, [Norbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887) will be considerably simpler to use, but there may be edge cases.  In particular, using a compatibility fix may be preferable if your program is not directly responsible for launching the problematic executable.)