# Why is Windows asking for system administrator privileges for running executables with "install" in their name?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am building a tool which allows to install an application into our simulator and it is called 'cl-install.exe'. It really doesn't need any administrator privileges to run. But Windows 7 always pops up a dialog asking the user to provide administrator privileges when this command is invoked from the command prompt.

If I rename the same executable to some other name, without the words 'install' or 'setup' in it, Windows doesn't ask for admin privileges.

Is there any way I can prevent Windows from doing this, without renaming my executable?

Comment: One possible workaround, depending on context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is part of the heuristics present in Windows Vista and later. From [here](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGIQFjAC&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/C/D/8CD015BB-081B-49C5-A506-9C9B570B8DD2/InstallerDetection.pptx&ei=R-8IUPCxDsemhAe4mMH6CQ&usg=AFQjCNHXcaCOv_FFndx0mxn7eovywzKQMg&sig2=WO6YA8Bahm0zOiqZH7P-GQ) if the file contains the words "install", "setup", "update" or "patch" - installer is assumed.

You can prevent this by adding the following to your manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" />
```

Comment: I love this site.  I learn 10 new things every day.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I created a file called 'cl-install.exe.manifest' in the same directory as my executable and added the line you have given. When running the file now, I get something like: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...". My executable is not an installer. It is a simple custom utility built with MinGW GCC.

Comment: You need to properly embed the manifest in your executable.  Hopefully a search of stackoverflow will help you work out how to do this in MinGW, if not, ask a new question.

Comment: Sorrt, I actually chickened out and changed my executable name a little. Anyway, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a working solution here: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/156

Quote:

The solution is to write a manifest file listed below for the executables, in order to persuade UAC that it does not require administrative privilege.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <!-- Make sure that UAC believes
        that it does not require administrative privilege -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

The filenames of the manifest files should be install.exe.manifest and patch.exe.manifest, and then put them in the same folder as install.exe and patch.exe.

If the UAC prompt still pops up, change the timestamp of install.exe and patch.exe to persuade Windows to pick up the new manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly you can disable this behaviour the following way (quoted from [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)):

1. Click **Start**, click **All Programs**, click **Accessories**, click Run, type **secpol.msc** in the **Open** text box, and then click **OK**.
2. From the **Local Security Settings** console tree, click **Local Policies**, and then click **Security Options**.
3. Scroll down and double-click **User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation**.
4. Select the **Disabled** option, and then click **OK**.
5. Close the **Local Security Settings** window.

You may need to re-logon for the setting to take effect.