# How to execute console EXEs without spawning a new console window?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, console, py2exe

I have a Python script which is usually called from the Windows PowerShell, with some command line arguments. I want to distribute this script in a .exe format, and I want to keep the same "user interface", based on the console, for its usage.

1. The user opens the Windows Powershell.
2. The user calls the myscript.exe program from the shell:

   ```
   myscript.exe argument1 argument2 argument3
   ```
3. The program executes in *the same console* and writes its output in *the same console*.

Actually I have a myscript.exe program, which of course gets the arguments from the PowerShell, but, unfortunately, executes the program in another console which is spawned at the call.

How can I avoid this behaviour and keep everything in the same console?

**EDIT:**
I have followed the tutorial on http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial.

For my setup.py build file I used:

- The `console` keyword (providing myscript.py as the only element in the list)
- The `zipfile` keyword (Set to True)
- The `options` keyword with `optimize: 2`,  `bundle_files: 1`, and `compressed: True`.

The compilation works ok, and the program does what it is supposed to do. The only undesirable thing is the opening of a dedicated console instead of executing in the same console.

**EDIT2:** Here is exactly my setup.py code.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, 'optimize': 2}},
    console = [{'script': "myscript.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

I simply call the script typing:

```
python setup.py
```

in Windows Powershell

**EDIT3:**
This has been done on Windows 8.1 with:

- Python 3.4.2
- py2exe 0.9.2.2
- Powershell 4.0

The final executable has also been tested on a Windows 10 system without any Python installation; it worked but showed the same console-spawning behaviour.

Comment: hm, usually, python just prints to `stdout`, meaning that no second console window should open. Then again, I'm not really a windows user...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was just about to say the same thing. Might be that `py2exe` compiles the executable in a way so that it always spawns a new console host

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a py2exe feature. But I'd like to know how to avoid it.

Comment: Then you need to tell us how exactly you built the executable. Did you follow the [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)?

Comment: I have edited the initial question with the details you requested.

Comment: What happens if you execute this from a standard DOS command prompt rather than a Windows Powershell?

Comment: Tried with the command prompt... same behaviour.

Comment: Updated the original question with the software versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I have found an answer by myself with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573444/why-is-windows-asking-for-system-administrator-privileges-for-running-executable), linked by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682345/3789324). The issue was also connected to this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682171/py2exe-avoid-windows-to-request-permission-to-execute-exe-file/) question. A common cause generated two different but related problems.

It is caused by the .exe file name. Switching to a different file name, stops the UAC to ask for admin privileges and executes the software in the same shell.

The name was:

```
<project_name_under_NDA>_update.exe
```

But switching to

```
try.exe
```

It worked.

Comment: Here's an [example setup.py](http://pastebin.com/rsrsWZZv) that embeds a manifest in the executable requesting "asInvoker" execution level. This way you don't have to rename the file.

Comment: If this works for you (it does for me in Windows 10), then please include it in your answer as a more explicit alternative to changing the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following might help. This works fine for me both in a standard `Windows Command Prompt`, and whilst using the `Windows PowerShell`:

**test.py**

```
import sys

print "Arguments passed:"

for arg in sys.argv:
    print '  {}'.format(arg)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    zipfile = None,
    options = {"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 1}},
    console = [r'test.py'])
```

It is created using:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Here is an example execution:

```
PS E:\test> .\test.exe hello world
Arguments passed:
  E:\test\test.exe
  hello
  world
```

If this still produces a separate shell, are there any environment variables of PowerShell settings that could be altering your result?

I have tested this in `Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (32-bit)` and `py2exe 0.6.9`.

Comment: I have added the code... it seems almost the same code you used.

Comment: Are you able to test your EXE on a different PC?

Comment: Yes, sure. It worked on another PC, on Windows 10 without any Python installation.