# Py2Exe: avoid windows to request permission to execute .exe file

Tags: windows, powershell, console, py2exe, privileges

I have a py2exe-built program which is executed directly from the console (Windows Powershell). Involved modules are: xlrd and PrettyTable.

Unfortunately, each time the program is called, Windows asks the user for a confirmation, as the program would need particular privileges.

This is undesirable as the script is "safe" for the system. It just gets text files as arguments and outputs a text file, in the same folder. I don't want the user to be scared by this permission request.

Is there any way to avoid such behaviour?

Comment: If you are asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt for administrative permissions, the answer is no. Use the "what if this were possible" thought experiment. This is what all malware would do.

Comment: No, I am not asking such a dumb question. Just trying to understand what py2exe does to activate the UAC,  why and what can I do with it as there are no malware here, nor particular operations but text file processing.

Comment: So, it's not py2exe's fault. Just a matter of file naming.

Comment: Understood. Sorry for assuming a dumb question, but you would be amazed how common that question is (how can I bypass UAC?).

Comment: Nevermind, I can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible; usually the reason for an executable requiring admininstrator or privileges or special permissions in newer versions of Windows is that it modifies something in your file system. Since your using an Excel File Module, your are probably accessing the hard drive, which worries the system because it thinks your application might mess with something important. (Like what malware, viruses and other junk does) But since its not installing anything executable, this Stackoverflow question might have your answer:

(if you have access to a Manifest File)

[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573444/why-is-windows-asking-for-system-administrator-privileges-for-running-executable)

Otherwise, there might be nothing you can do about it, as Windows is just built that way

Comment: So, it seems that a manifest file should be distributed as an "attachment" to the .exe file. Now I'm wondering if the manifest file is embeddable in the .exe file itself or not.

Comment: The answer you linked helped me solving the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have found an answer by myself with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573444/why-is-windows-asking-for-system-administrator-privileges-for-running-executable), linked by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682345/3789324). The issue was also connected to this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681189/how-to-execute-console-exe-in-the-same-shell-from-which-they-are-called) question. A common cause generated two different but related problems.

It is caused by the .exe file name. Switching to a different file name, stops the UAC to ask for admin privileges (and executes the software in the same shell, which solves the other question).

The name was:

```
<project_name_under_NDA>_update.exe
```

But switching to

```
try.exe
```

It worked.