# Why does patch.d require administrator privileges?

Tags: d, elevated-privileges, dmd

I'm running DMD32 D Compiler v2.071.1, on Windows 8.1 (latest update as of 09/19/2016).

When I compile a D file that contains "patch" in the file name, the resulting executable asks for admin privileges. Why?

---

If I name my file `foo.d`, everything is fine:

```
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> echo int main(string[] argv) { return 0; } > foo.d
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> dmd foo.d
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> foo.exe
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

---

But if I name it `patch.d`, suddenly I need admin privileges:

```
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> echo int main(string[] argv) { return 0; } > patch.d
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> dmd patch.d
C:\Users\sorbet\Desktop> patch.exe
```

[image: UAC]

Huh?

---

This also happens if I name it something that contains "patch" in the filename, like `foopatch.d`. Why is this happening, and can I disable it?

Comment: [It's probably the same thing that also causes files called `install.exe` and `update.exe` to request admin privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573444/why-is-windows-asking-for-system-administrator-privileges-for-running-executable). Try renaming the file to something completely different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not related to D Language, or DMD. It is a 'feature' in Windows.
Windows checks if the filename of the executable to execute is/has `setup.exe` or `*-setup`, or `installer.exe` or `*-installer` in it. The same applies for `patch`. Windows assumes that since programs like setups/installers/patches usually require administrative privileges, it asks the user (you) for administrative privileges.

TL;DR: Windows assumes that a program needs administrative privileges if the name has `setup`, `installer`, `patch`, etc.. Just change the filename, it'll be fixed.

Comment: Depending on which version of Windows you're running, you should be able to change the UAC settings or could change to be a non-administrator so that these annoying prompts won't occur. I always run as a non-admin, and have another admin account, and the UAC elevation prompting was turned off.