# How to run as adminstrator?

Tags: java, windows, xcode, passwords, administrator

The computers in my class are hooked up too a hdd drive that is connected to all the computers using ethernet and wifi. I have a java program i need to install to all the computers so everyone can run it, but how can i put it on the drive and after the students drag the program to their desktop, how can they run the program if it keeps asking for administrator permission (because the program only works if it runs as administrator), and we don't have that? Is there some code i can put in the java program to bypass the password so it can run as administrator?

Comment: If the program doesn't *really* need to run as administrator (often the case) this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't bypass it. You need to type in your credentials as the administrator or make each of your students administrators on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is to do with windows user account control which checks before even the program can be ran.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the program and click `run as administrator`