# Is there any way to run a .exe file in Windows 7 without admin privelages

Tags: windows, macros, installation, exe, administrator

So I am currently trying to get a macro running, and because our systems have recently upgraded to windows 7, now it is a long procedure to get anything installed on them, since none of us have admin rights.

I am either looking to install the macro software, which has an .exe install file, or create a .exe file with the macro software on another PC, and then use the macro that has been compiled into a .exe file on the windows 7 computer

Either way, I keep coming across the issue of not being an administrator on the computer, so it won't let me go any further with the file.

Is there any way around this? Or is there any keyboard macro software out there that doesn't require an exe file to be installed?

Isn't anything dodgey by the way.... is just something i made on XP that makes my tedious job that little bit easier!!

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887 ; if that doesn't work, it is likely that the admins have configured the machine to prevent unapproved software from running.  Talk to the admins about adding your software to the approved list.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need such tools approved by your administrator to use it unless you are a privileged user to begin with, and even then there are normally restrictions on what you can use.

As to macro tool, if you don't get an answer here you could try [**superuser.com**](https://superuser.com/) (experienced computer users), and / or [**serverfault.com**](https://serverfault.com/) (system administrators). I am sure there is one out there that doesn't require admin rights.