# How can I run Visual Studio as a non-administrator?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1, elevated-privileges, runas

I seem to be unable to start Visual Studio 2015 as a non-Administrator in Windows 8.1 Pro. I have tried:

- Deleting all VS references from:

  - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`
  - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store`
- Running it from a non-elevated command line
- Right clicking the executable, selecting 'Open' (not Run As Administrator)
- Verifying the shortcut is not marked 'Run As Administrator'

However, no matter what I do, it always starts with `(Administrator)` in the title bar, which causes it to attempt database connections with `DOMAIN\PCNAME$` instead of `DOMAIN\user`.

How can I force the execution as a non-administrator, or find out what is causing it to persistently run as administrator?

Comment: Have you checked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289173(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Have you disabled UAC?

Comment: As a last resort or temporary measure, [this should work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887) although I would hope there is a better solution.

Comment: I have disabled UAC.

Comment: @KristoferKällsbo I'm not going to make my domain account a non-administrator, as the article suggests.