# Running program as regular user from an elevated process

Tags: c++, windows

I have a process running with elevated privileges in Windows.  Now, from that process, I need to spawn another process, but without elevated privileges.

Right now, when I use `ShellExecuteEx()`, the process is starting with elevated privileges, which is not what I want.

Here's everything I tried up to now:

I get the user token of the logged on user (which doesn't have elevated privileges) and I use that in these functions:

`CreateProcessWithTokenW()`: fails with `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED`.

`CreateProcessAsUser()`: fails with `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`.

`ShellExecuteEx`(): starts a process with elevated privileges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643)

Comment: How did you obtain the restricted token?

Comment: @MartinDrab from explorer.exe

Comment: `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` may mean that the executable you're trying to run requires elevation.  If so, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887) might help.